# Gutenberg frontend block styles not applying

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I have a block registered that adds different styles to the editor and front end of a block display.

The editor styles are showing, but I can't get the frontend styles to show.

Here is what I have in my index.php file:

```
<?php

defined('ABSPATH') || exit;

// add_action engueue_block_editor_assets
add_action( 'enqueue_block_editor_assets', 'block_examples_02_stylesheets_block_enqueue_block_editor_assets');

// plugin-name_block-name_function-name
function block_examples_02_stylesheets_block_enqueue_block_editor_assets() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        // name of script
        'block-examples_02-stylesheets-block-editor',
        // full url of script location
        plugins_url( 'block.build.js', __FILE__ ),
        // dependencies of script
        array( 'wp-blocks', 'wp-i18n', 'wp-element' ),
        // version number
        filemtime( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__) . 'block.build.js')
    );

    wp_enqueue_style(
        'block-examples_02-stylesheets-block-editor',
        plugins_url( 'editor.css', __FILE__ ),
        array('wp-edit-blocks'),
        filemtime( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__) . 'editor.css')
    );

}

// add_action engueue_block_editor_assets
add_action( 'enqueue_block_assets', 'block_examples_02_stylesheets_block_enqueue_block_assets');

// plugin-name_block-name_function-name
function block_examples_02_stylesheets_block_enqueue_block_assets() {

    wp_enqueue_style(
        'block-examples_02-stylesheets-block',
        plugins_url( 'style.css', __FILE__ ),
        array('wp-blocks'),
        filemtime( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__) . 'style.css')
    );

}
```

Comment: Can you please share register_block_type block code or add editor_style in register_block_type to load style in editor.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it appears that removing 'wp-blocks' fixes the issue and the block is now reflecting the styling from the style.css file.

```
// add_action engueue_block_editor_assets
add_action( 'enqueue_block_assets', 'block_examples_02_stylesheets_block_enqueue_block_assets');

// plugin-name_block-name_function-name
function block_examples_02_stylesheets_block_enqueue_block_assets() {

    wp_enqueue_style(
        'block-examples_02-stylesheets-block',
        plugins_url( 'style.css', __FILE__ ),
        array(),
        filemtime( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__) . 'style.css')
    );

}
```